# How to Determine if an Intrusion in the Firewall Log was Successful or Not?

Tags: firewalls

Is there any way, in looking at the firewall/system log to tell?  I realize these events are very common these days.

However, I want to make sure that they didn't get through the firewall and that it is not a more targeted attack.

What was concerning is that the network went down twice last night and I'm not sure why as there were no known outages in the area.  Is it possible that there was a DDOS attack or could an unusually high number of intrusion attempts cause the downtime?  I reset the router twice both times it happened.  Unfortunately, the logs reset every day but I do have intrusion events from this morning to examine.

For more clarification, this is the built-in firewall on a generic consumer-grade router.  I'm looking at firewall entries which are below. The MAC has been X'ed out as has the DST IP.  The word blocked isn't mentioned anywhere.  Please let me know if I can gather more data that might be useful.

```
Intrusion -> IN=ptm0.1 OUT= MAC=X SRC=80.94.95.245 DST=X LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=238 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=53315 DPT=8443
Intrusion -> IN=ptm0.1 OUT= MAC=X SRC=97.107.141.150 DST=X LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=242 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=51872 DPT=44
Intrusion -> IN=ptm0.1 OUT= MAC=X SRC=45.143.200.50 DST=X LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=235 ID=35073 PROTO=TCP SPT=45932 DPT=600
Intrusion -> IN=ptm0.1 OUT= MAC=X SRC=45.143.200.50 DST=X LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=235 ID=13584 PROTO=TCP SPT=45932 DPT=305
Intrusion -> IN=ptm0.1 OUT= MAC=X SRC=92.63.197.110 DST=X LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=242 ID=58413 PROTO=TCP SPT=54319 DPT=612
Intrusion -> IN=ptm0.1 OUT= MAC=X SRC=178.32.43.185 DST=X LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=238 ID=28053 PROTO=TCP SPT=60000 DPT=573
Intrusion -> IN=ptm0.1 OUT= MAC=X SRC=77.90.185.150 DST=X LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=241 ID=24350 PROTO=TCP SPT=42912 DPT=284
```

Comment: What firewall?  What OS System log?  Please include log examples as well.

Comment: This is a really unfocused question. You appear to ask about this in general terms, on one hand, but appear to also want us to provide specific advice on a specific incident on the other.

Comment: If the firewall says that something was blocked, then it was blocked. What you need to know is what was ***not*** blocked. And for that you need other data and logs.

Comment: Ok, then with the data you have, you can't determine what was successful. To figure out what was caught and what wasn't, you need tons of data, and devices that have the capacity to capture that data to help you analyse it. Your generic router isn't designed for this type of analysis.

Comment: While I appreciate your replying, you indicated that my question was unfocused.  When I provided more detail, your next comment was unfocused.  What kind of data do I need?  What kind of device do I need?  Just a better router or something like a firewalla?  Or perhaps another security appliance?

Comment: My response was very foused: there is no way to answer given the data you have. New devices won't help you figure out what happened in the past. And the analysis of this specific event is what you appear to be asking about. If you want to know about how to analyse future events, then, like I said, you need different devices that can provide more data and more detailed logs, like for instance, what was *not* blocked.